# A quick way to copy the word before the cursor

Tags: copy-paste, words

By `M-backspace` (or by `M-x backward-kill-word`), I can remove the word before the cursor. Is there a built-in equivalent of this command for copying instead of deleting?

Obviously one can do `M-x backward-kill-word` then `M-x yank` (or `M-x undo`), but I am wondering if there is a better solution (aside from not to be so quick, the inconvenience is that it first changes the status of the buffer).

Comment: I usually do `C-M--` (control meta hyphen) `C-M-SPC` `M-w`

Answer (score 6):

`C-u -1 M-@ M-w` or define a new command yourself, something like

```
(defun backward-copy-word ()
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (copy-region-as-kill (point) (progn (backward-word) (point)))))
```

Comment: Your second solution seems to not working. It seems to copy the word *after* the point and If there is no text after the point, the cursor jumps below (the first solution is essentially the one given by @JennyD.)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't test it, the `forward-word` should be replaced with `backward-word` obviously, I've changed it, should work now.

Comment: Basically the same thing but faster to type: M-- C-M-SPC M-w. You can use M-- (or C--) to specify a negative argument, which will be treated the same as `C-u - 1`. C-M-SPC calls `mark-sexp`, which will mark a word in most cases.

Answer (score 3):

`C-u - 1 M-x mark-word` will give `-1` as an argument to mark-word, thus marking the previous word. After that, `M-w` will copy it to the kill ring without actually deleting it, making it available to paste elsewhere.

Comment: Ok, this selects the word before the point, but still one has to copy it.

Comment: @Name I've added that, testing now that the solution makes the copied word available both in the X buffer and in the emacs kill ring.

Comment: `C-u - 1` can be simplified to just `C--` (ctrl minus).

Comment: To add to @glucas, `C--` runs `negative-argument` which is also bound to `C-M--` and `M--` for ease of combining with other keystrokes.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you use [expand-region](http://melpa.org/#/expand-region), when point is after a word you can just:

1. Press its binding (I use <kbd>M-SPC</kbd>).
2. Press <kbd>M-w</kbd>.

This also works if point is before or within the word.

You can also repeat step 1 to mark semantically bigger chunks of text.

Comment: thank you, interesting package, it has also other useful functionalities.

Comment: Yes, expand-region is awesome.

Answer (score 1):

Emacs doesn't have a native way to copy words, but you can always write a function and and bind a key to that using examples from https://emacswiki.org/emacs/CopyWithoutSelection

```
(defun get-point (symbol &optional arg)
      "get the point"
      (funcall symbol arg)
      (point)
    )

(defun copy-backward-word ()
 "copy word before point"
  (interactive "")
  (save-excursion
   (let ((end (point))
     (beg (get-point 'backward-word 1)))
     (copy-region-as-kill beg end)))
  )

(global-set-key (kbd "C-c !") 'copy-backward-word) ;; Adapt this.
```

Marking a word though is easy:

`M- -1 M-x mark-word` or assuming default bindings `M- -1 M-@`

Comment: Sorry, typo. "Meta - 1" then "M-x mark word".

Comment: Ok, this selects the word before the point, but still one has to copy it.